# Using PRF as a building block to build other primitives?

Tags: signature, algorithm-design, pseudo-random-function

I am doing an independent research in cryptography. I have designed a post-quantum secure pseudo random function.

Just constructing a PRF will not help me to publish in reputed journals. I was thinking to use the PRF I designed as a building block to build some other primitive?

Can someone suggest me something? In which direction I can proceed. What are some primitives which can be solely designed using PRF?

Comment: Maybe try to extend your PRF to a Verifiable Random Function (VRF) or try to build an Oblivious PRF (OPRF) or a verifiable OPRF from your PRF. In certain Private-Set Intersection protocols Oblivious Programmable PRFs are applied extensively. Hope this helps.

Comment: In the "classic" setting you can use PRF with a Feistel network to create a PRP, but I don't know how useful this is for the/(your) post-quantum setting.

Comment: @IstvánAndrásSeres Thanks for the comment. It is really helpful.

Comment: @Titanlord Thank you. I will look into this.

Comment: I am working on a new Private Set Intersection solution and as part of this need to use a batch OPRF. So, maybe this could be a practical use of the post quantum secure PRF? Assume your PRF can be extended to batch OPRF?

Comment: "I have designed a post-quantum secure pseudo random function"; do you mean that you have a proof that your PRF is secure even if the attacker has a Quantum Computer?  Or, do you mean that you can't think of a way of attacking it?  As for the latter, we already have PRFs that, to the best of our knowledge, are secure - what extra does your idea bring to the table?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; on suggestion of @DannyNiu it was [opened a chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135550/discussion-on-question-by-shweta-aggrawal-using-prf-as-a-building-block-to-build) to discuss the "proposal for collaboration" in an earlier comment by Stephen.